# IE10 fonts work on live site, but not dev site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-10

I have a dev site for a store here where fonts are not showing properly in IE10: http://darciekentvineyards.com.uswest.vin65dev.com/Wines

They work on the live portion of the site in IE10: http://darciekentvineyards.com/about

They also work in Chrome.

I'm not sure what's causing this or why there's a scrollbar on the menu. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by restrictions on cross-origin use of fonts, as you can see if you press F12 in IE and select Console from the IE developer tool, then open the dev site in the browser. There are many error messages in the consolte about resource loading failing due to cross-origin request.

The simple solution is to upload the fonts onto the dev site too.